# Boost unit test running absurd amount of tests

Tags: c++, boost

So I'm using the boost unit test to run a bunch of test cases for my code.

When I run my tests I get the following odd results

```
Boost running 33 test cases...
Boost running 4294967295 test cases...
```

Does anyone know what common errors can cause the second line to occur? And why does the second line even happen since the first already occured?

Thanks for any information.

Comment: 4294967295 is `unsigned(-1)`. You could be overwriting memory. Try running the test under `valgrind`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anyone know what common errors can cause the second line to occur?

For example, the following code produces this value:

```
unsigned start = 5;
unsigned end = 4;
unsigned count = end - start; // will be 4294967295
```